# Adding character to inner join statement 

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, inner-join

I'm working on a SQL Server database where `db1.dbo.batches.id` is stored as `1234` but `db2.dbo.activity.batch_id` is stored as `B1234`.

I am trying to join the two tables, something like this...

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM db1.dbo.batches AS b
INNER JOIN db2.dbo.activity AS a
ON ('B' + b.id) = a.batch_id
```

The issue is the `('B' + b.id)`. I have tried `CONCAT('B' + b.id)`, `CAST('B' + b.id)`, and `CONVERT(varchar(10),'B' + b.id)` none of which have worked.

I can run a second select query but I was hoping for something more elegant.

Any ideas? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the 'B' outside of the CONVERT function:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM db1.dbo.batches AS b
INNER JOIN db2.dbo.activity AS a
ON 'B' + CONVERT(varchar(10), b.id) = a.batch_id
```

Comment: That worked thanks mate! So the issue was the id was stored as an int so I couldn't simple + it to the 'B'.

Comment: Correct, which is why it wouldn't let you concatenate the values inside the CAST/CONVERT functions... it tried to concatenate them before converting, which caused an exception.